# Non-linear regression, force the curve to go through a starting point

Tags: matlab, regression, interpolation

I have two sets of points:

```
x=[300  292 310 330]
y=[0.01 60  120 160]
```

[image]

I need to find curve of best fit through those points. I know it has a form:
$$x=C_1+C_2\text{log}(y)+C_3y$$

Using nlinfit in Matlab does the job as shown:[image]

But the problem I have is that the curve does not start at the initial point (0.01, 300) and I need it to start at this exact point. How to achieve this?

Comment: Well, if you want to **force** it through that point, it creates the condition
$$
C_1  - 2 C_2  + 0.01 C_3 = 300
$$
You can choose one of the coefficients, solve that from this equation and then replace that in the original equation. Then you should have an expression with only two $C$-terms.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to replace $C_1$ by $300+2C_2 - 0.01C_3$...

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!